# Bottom Sheet Fragment comes up with keyboard

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have an edit text inside a bottom sheet fragment. when the focus come on the edit text the layout goes up . i tried

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

its work for the parent activity but not for the dialog fragment.

This is my bottom sheet class:

```
public class CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_dialog_bottom_sheet, container, false);
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        return v;
    }
}
```

initial state

[image]

when keyboard comes up

[image]

i want the layout to always stay on the bottom the keyboard should come above the layout.

check the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottomSheetLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:behavior_hideable="true"
app:behavior_peekHeight="60dp"
app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="10dp" />

<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edt" />
```

Comment: Have you tried it programmatically ? Post screen shot to get more idea.

Comment: can you please give me code of your bottomsheet Fragment of it i wanna same as your bottomsheet above keyboard as you are implemented above.. @DKV

Answer (score 34, accepted):

> Use this in your `Dialog Fragment`.

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

> Inside `onCreateView` like this.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_fragment, container);

        //set to adjust screen height automatically, when soft keyboard appears on screen 
        getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);


        return rootView;
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

> I have made some changes with what `layout` you are using make it apply in your current `layout`.

Here is `layout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="60dp"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:padding="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edt" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Here is `Fragment`.

```
public class TestFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test4, container, false);
        return v;
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

> You can try *android:elevation="50dp"* property for shadow above *Bottom Sheet* give a try with that in *frame layout*.

[image]

Comment: @VV Post your *dialog fragment code* and also screen shot with reproducing exact issue. Show me your `onCreateDialog` method.

Comment: @VV Post your *code* and screen shot to get exact issue. Without that nobody can guide you ahead with this issue.

Comment: please check the update. let me know you want any more details.

Comment: @VV Could you show me your what your `layout` *content_dialog_bottom_sheet* contains.

Comment: @ jaydroider  : please check the layout

Comment: @VV Check i have edited my answer and use `layout` i have made and `fragment` both replace with yours. check the working screen shot also.

Comment: @VV Sry i didn't get you!! which `activity` ? Please explain bit more.

Comment: i done what u told me to do. but it is not working. did do miss anything that u have done

Comment: @VV I have not added anything using *Activity*. I have just changes your *layout* and *fragment* code just replace both. What problem you are facing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122727/discussion-between-jaydroider-and-v-v).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122827/discussion-between-v-v-and-jaydroider).

Comment: @jaydroider Any care we have to take care if we are using the above content inside  CoordinatorLayout with AppBarLayout ?   we have to replace ScrollView with  NestedScrollView?

Comment: @jaydroider say for above example if we have 10 edit text full screen content, scroll conflict may occur even though we have locked the BottomSheetDialogFragment behaviour !

Comment: added app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" to content ,  app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior" to CoordinatorLayout , but nothing seems to be working, scrolling doesn't adjust to the keyboard hight!!

Comment: @jaydroider any help available for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664858/android-soft-keyboard-overlays-the-edittext-in-recyclerview-in-bottomsheet#comment71737250_40664858

Comment: have solution for custom view? my bottom sheet is not dialog fragment

Comment: @IliyaMashin Please ask a new Question with exact issue and details will look into it.

Comment: @JayRathodRJ already did https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56199388/bottom-sheet-not-dialog-fragment-open-with-keyboard

Answer (score 17):

100% working formula for BottomSheetFragment

Use this in onCreateDialog in BottomSheetFragment

```
KeyboardUtil(getActivity(), view);
```

or

For fragment use

```
new KeyboardUtil(this, findViewById(R.id.fragment_container));
```

by using this Util class

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/aa9136fb4f5b3a80460fe5f47213985026d20c88/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/util/KeyboardUtil.java

Credit:Mikepenz

Comment: What about the enable and disable methods, where are you using them?

Comment: this helped me, my colleague recommended your answer. had been looking for this all over the internet.

Comment: this worked for me, but I just have to replace these two lines in the class
 //get screen height and calculate the difference with the useable area from the r
            int height = contentView.getHeight();
            int diff = (int) (height - r.bottom  + r.top + decorView.getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._16dp));

Answer (score 5):

Seems like there is bug in the older design version.
I encountered the same problem, but after I **upgraded the design version**, adjustnothing can work as expected.

In gradle:

```
com.android.support:design:26.1.0
```

In your BottomSheetDialog:

```
getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your flag from

`adjustNothing`

to

`adjustPan`

Check the [Official Document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the following problem

[image]

solution

```
      sheetDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the activity declaration in the manifest, put these lines of code:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
android:windowTranslucentNavigation="true"
android:windowTranslucentStatus="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the decor view of the dialog and set the bottom padding to height `0` or your dialog height.

```
getDialog.getWindow.getDecorView.setpadding(0,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same scenario, Instead of EditText I used SearchView.A keyboard was not hidden when BottomSheetDialog goes to the hidden state.

Simply call this **search_channel_template.clearFocus();**

I will share my code which I was used to hiding the Keyboard.

```
search_channel_template = (SearchView) bottomSheetDialog.findViewById(R.id.search_channel_template);

txtVw_template_headerBS_down_id.setOnClickListener(new OnSingleClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSingleClick(View v) {
                search_channel_template.clearFocus();
                bottomSheetDialog.getBehavior().setState(BottomSheetBehaviorv2.STATE_HIDDEN);
            }
        });
```