# Replicate keyboard like layout upward push in bottom sheet

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

Is there any way to manually push up layout (scrollview or recyclerview or whole activity) when bottom sheet opens just like android keyboard does? 
Or you can say that i want to make a minimal keyboard in form of a bottom sheet(which isn't using any editable view)

Comment: Got any solution ? Let me know it's solved by this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288879/bottom-sheet-fragment-comes-up-with-keyboard

Comment: This still seems to be just for keyboard behaviour..Not bottomsheet behaviour

Comment: let me know the feedback on my answer it should work fine , are you using coordinated layout and scrollview as a parent view  for your forms edittextfields?

Comment: Yea scroll view wrapped by coordinator..I will try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100% working formula

Use this in onCreateDialog in BottomSheetFragment

```
KeyboardUtil(getActivity(), view);
```

or

For fragment use

```
new KeyboardUtil(this, findViewById(R.id.fragment_container));
```

by using this Util class

https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/aa9136fb4f5b3a80460fe5f47213985026d20c88/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/util/KeyboardUtil.java

Credit:Mikepenz

Comment: it worked ..thanks..though required minor changes.The idea of setting padding to the content was the required thing

Comment: great, do share if you get any better solution !

Comment: Can anybody share some code on how this was accomplished please? I was able to add the bottom sheet to my current layout, but currently when clicking on my layout, it is not pushing the whole layout out. I'm doubting that I'm not implementing the new KeybordUtil correctly.

Comment: @LOG_TAG Got any solution for BottomSheetBehavior ?

Comment: @RamithDR what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: In some devices like Samsung, this was not the ideal case. The layout was already being pushed up with the keyboard and the padding was additionally applied to push the layout further upwards.

Comment: @Debdeep, how did you solve for the extra padding on the devices you mentioned? Was facing a similar issue & don't have a solve yet.

Comment: @AnkitWadhawan See this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/57089779/5685358. Might be of some help.