# Show entire bottom sheet with EditText above Keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet

I'm implementing a UI where a bottom sheet will appear above the keyboard with an EditText for the user to enter a value. The problem is the View is being partially overlapped by the keyboard, covering up the bottom of the bottom sheet.

Here is the Bottom Sheet and no keyboard.

[image: Bottom Sheet]

Here is the Bottom Sheet with the keyboard showing.

[image]

What's the best method to ensure the entire Bottom Sheet is shown?

Thanks.

Comment: "android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" " in activity inside manifest file where you declare your activity.it will prevent keyboard popup till then you touch in the edittext.

Comment: I need the keyboard to show up so people can enter their values.

Comment: they can give values by clicking on the edittext. The keyboard will popup after it was clicked. So do not worry about it. Try once.

Comment: I did, the same thing happens if the keyboard is up before or after. It'll still cover the bottom of the view.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50948146/7958563

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625365/keyboard-hides-bottomsheetdialogfragment.

Comment: Just add this to your BottomSheetDialogFragment "getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)"

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Just reposting @jblejder from this question [Keyboard hides BottomSheetDialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44625365/keyboard-hides-bottomsheetdialogfragment/50948146#50948146) since it worked for me, to make it easier for others to find:

The most convenient way that I found to change this is by creating style:

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

And set this in onCreate method of your BottomSheetDialogFragment:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle)
}
```

This is how it looks on my device:

[image]

==== UPDATE ====

As already mentioned in the Comments a few times, you might also need to set the state of the BottomSheetDialog to STATE_EXPANDED like in Nordknight's answer below

```
dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getContext(), R.style.BottomSheetDialog);  
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
@Override
public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
                    FrameLayout bottomSheet = d.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                    BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                }
            },0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Before a keyboard appeared above `EditText`, so `EditText` lifted up and allowed to type, but not press a `Button` below. After I applied your solution, nothing changed.

Comment: Works when bottom sheet fragment layout's root is ScrollView

Comment: works like a charm. For dynamic bottomsheet just set it style when declaring. BottomSheetDialog bd = new BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.DialogStyle);

Comment: it works, but you need to set state expanded to BottomSheetDialog => this solution + https://stackoverflow.com/a/50798800/5698198

Comment: @CoolMind I was also having the same issue. To solve this I override onShow(DialogInterface dialog) and added  BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) along with the code posted in this answer.

Comment: this  works only when i wrapped ConstraintLayout with NestedScrollView (ScrollView is not working)

Comment: Just add following lines in onCreateDialog() along with above style in OnCreateView(). 

`override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
  val bottomSheetDialog =  super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
        if(bottomSheetDialog is BottomSheetDialog){
            bottomSheetDialog.behavior.skipCollapsed = true
            bottomSheetDialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
        }
        return bottomSheetDialog
}`

Comment: If anyone faced issues with the style, try changing `parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog"` to `parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog"` or whatever your app theme is.

Answer (score 21):

This might be a redundant answer. Although just pointing out the issue.
If you're using `BottomSheetDialogFragment`, the only way is to enable the attribute [android:windowIsFloating](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#isFloating%28%29) to **true**. This will enable the whole window to be on top of whatever is trying to take the space behind it.

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogThemeNoFloating" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize|stateVisible</item>
</style>
```

Then in your `onCreate()` of your dialog, set this style.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // set the window no floating style
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppRoundedBottomSheetDialogThemeNoFloating)
}
```

This is handy for those who frequently use bottom sheets and may want to deal with `EditText` and soft keyboard overlapping each other.

Note: The class `KeyboardUtil` by mikepenz has an issue in which on certain phones, the content view with input field is automatically pushed above keyboard despite giving bottom padding to the whole content view supplied.

Comment: This has worked for me when using ```BottomSheetDialogFragment```

Comment: If I do this then I am not able to see my corner radius.

Comment: Where to place this style xml ? which path please

Comment: You say "set it to `true`", but write `<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>`. Which one is it?

Answer (score 10):

Some answers seem to do the trick better than others but will need modification when using the new material design components instead of the older support libraries while also using kotlin

Hope this will help someone.

```
BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.DialogStyle).apply {
    setContentView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, null))
    window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)
    findViewById<EditText>(R.id.time_et)?.requestFocus()

    show()
}
```

layout/bottom_sheet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Time"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/time_et"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:inputType="numberSigned"
                            android:minWidth="50dp"
                            android:text="15" />

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                            android:text="min" />

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


        <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="#000"
                android:text="Save"
                android:textColor="#fff" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

styes.xml (Split for v-21 for using statusBarColor)

```
    <style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: This is the only DialogStyle that worked for me I use BottomSheetDialogFragment

Comment: Setting the `windowSoftInputMode`, specifically, was what did the trick for me with a BottomSheetDialogFragment.

        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>

Answer (score 9):

```
dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(getContext(), R.style.BottomSheetDialog);  
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
@Override
public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
                    FrameLayout bottomSheet = d.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                    BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
                    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                }
            },0);
        }
    });
```

This code works fine at Fragment's onCreateView method (thanks for ADM)

Comment: It reminds https://stackoverflow.com/a/45706484/2914140 (and doesn't work in my case).

Answer (score 9):

This is the easiest and best way to handle a BottomSheet dialog:

```
private fun enterMobileNumberPopUp() {                                         
val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(this,R.style.DialogStyle)
val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_otp, null)
dialog.setContentView(view)
dialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
dialog.show()}
```

[image]

Reference for `styles.xml`:

```
 <style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

Comment: really thank you man , you are a great support 
 <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>. solved my problem

Answer (score 7):

A `BottomSheetDialog` can be helpful for this. it will open with Softkeyboard open with focus on edit text.But user can still close the Softkeyboard and Dialog will be reset to Bottom. Again focusing will make dialog appear at top of Softkeyboard.

```
 public void showDialog()  {
    final BottomSheetDialog dialog=new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.item_dialog);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    dialog.show();
}
```

You can make the BottomSheetDialog expanded over keyboard . But for this you need to call it after SoftKeyboard Open. the Expand code is .

```
 BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

I have tested it on `DialogInterface.OnShowListener()` but its not working . Tested with it 1 second delay its working . But Delay is not the solution . You need to figure out the on which action you should expand the dialog.

```
 final BottomSheetDialog dialog=new BottomSheetDialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.item_dialog);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE|
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) dialog.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    },2000);
    dialog.show();
```

Comment: Using a `BottomSheetDialog` and it's still covering the bottom area below the `EditText`.

Comment: Yeah it is . Thats the behavior.

Comment: I'm trying to show the entire `BottomSheetDialog` so I can have things below the `EditText` and still have them visible.

Comment: I tried your `expand` code with a timer but it didn't have any effect for me.

Comment: Well i have tested it with `handler.postDelay()` and it worked.  Anyway try to look about `BottomSheetFragment` maybe it will work as you want.

Comment: I actually used `handler.postDelayed()` too, and I was using `BottomSheetFragment` before but it seems to be the same issue.

Comment: Ok i am posting what i have tested . You can have a look,its just a test code. Good luck .

Answer (score 6):

An updated answer for those using Material Components theme, and also an improved answer to remove the need to add anything into each dialog's `onCreate()`.

In your main AppTheme style, you can add the attribute `bottomSheetDialogTheme` to apply the style to *all* of your BottomSheetDialogFragments:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/BottomSheetDialogStyle</item>
  </style>
```

So with the above, no need to add anything to your BottomSheetDialogFragment code.

And then, as previous answers, your Dialog style, noting to also match the style to the same Material Components library (or you'll get some weird looking buttons, edittexts etc):

```
 <style name="BottomSheetDialogStyle" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
```

Note that I am adding my app theme colors back in here; as you can't have multiple inheritance in Android styles, you may want these colors defining here so any buttons and accents align with the rest of your app.

Answer (score 6):

```
        bottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

It will work for sure.

Comment: Where do you get bottomSheetDialog from?

Comment: from BottomSheetDialog class in Material. You can find it in documentation but to make it above the mobile keyboard you have to write the mentioned code

Answer (score 6):

If you are using bottom sheet fragment overeide getTheme(). setStyle haven't worked for me. Wrap your whole layout inside NestedScrollView

themes.xml

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/bottomSheetBackground</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize|stateVisible</item>
    </style>
```

Bottomsheet fragment

```
@Override
public int getTheme() {
    return R.style.BottomSheetDialogStyle;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just write the following programmatically

```
override fun setupDialog(dialog: Dialog, style: Int) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style)
        dialog.window?.setSoftInputMode(             WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE or 
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE
      );
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

This trick solved me

in manifest put

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in your activity
and

```
        bottomSheetDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    bottomSheetDialog.getBehavior().setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
```

Answer (score 2):

This one working

```
 BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.DialogStyle);
    View sheetView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_remark, null);
    Objects.requireNonNull(dialog.getWindow())
            .setSoftInputMode(SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    dialog.setContentView(sheetView);
    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            View bottomSheetInternal = d.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetInternal).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
```

add this style to your styles.xml

```
 <style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustPan</item>
</style>
```

add your layout like this

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/scrollview"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_margin="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserratmedium"
                android:text="Add Remarks"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserratmedium"
                android:text="Branch"
                android:textColor="#8B8B8B"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserratmedium"
                android:text="BLR-CO-SINDHUBHAVAN-384"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/montserratmedium"
                android:text="Enter Remarks"
                android:textColor="#8B8B8B"
                android:textSize="18sp" />


            <EditText

                android:id="@+id/input_remark"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/remark_inputbg"
                android:gravity="start"

                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="5" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/action"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/reset_bg"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text="CANCEL" />

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="#4F4DBB"
                        android:padding="8dp"
                        android:text="CANCEL"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Only `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"` in AndroidManifest did the trick for me. Thanks for.!

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin, +viewBinding, +by using the accepted answer's dialog style

```
val bottomSheet = BottomSheetDialog(this, R.style.BottomSheetDialogStyle)
val binding = [YourSheetBinding].inflate(LayoutInflater.from(YourActivity.this))
bottomSheet.setContentView(binding.root)
bottomSheet.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
bottomSheet.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    bottomSheetBehavior?.skipCollapsed = true
    bottomSheetBehavior?.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
}
```

Putting this in BottomSheet helped without setting styles and without ScrollView
(correct me if I'm wrong or if I'm missing something)

Answer (score 0):

For this, I found an `AlertDialog` worked best. While it doesn't sit flush against the bottom or side of the screen, it still looks good enough.

First, create the `AlertDialog` with your view.

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.alert, null)

dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
             .setView(view)
             .create()
```

Next, set the gravity.

```
    dialog.window.attributes.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
```

And finally, show it.

```
dialog.show()
```

You can also bind the keyboard to stay with the dialog, by using an `onDismissListener`.

After showing the `AlertDialog`, I force up the keyboard.

Call this method, passing in your `EditText`.

```
fun showKeyboard(view: View?) {
        if (view == null) return;

        val imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    }
```

And for dismissing within the `onDismissListener`.

```
private fun hideKeyboard() {
        val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer might be useful for someone who is still looking for solution. If keyboard is covering edittext in BottomSheetDialogFragment then in `setupDialog()` method create instance of a class KeyboardUtil and pass your rootview.

```
    @Override
    public void setupDialog(final Dialog dialog, int style) {
        super.setupDialog(dialog, style);
        View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.reopen_dialog_layout, null);
        new KeyboardUtil(getActivity(), view);
}
```

### Create a new class

```
    public class KeyboardUtil {
        private View decorView;
        private View contentView;
        //a small helper to allow showing the editText focus
        ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener onGlobalLayoutListener = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Rect r = new Rect();
                //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
                decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                //get screen height and calculate the difference with the useable area from the r
                int height = decorView.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
                int diff = height - r.bottom;

                //if it could be a keyboard add the padding to the view
                if (diff != 0) {
                    // if the use-able screen height differs from the total screen height we assume that it shows a keyboard now
                    //check if the padding is 0 (if yes set the padding for the keyboard)
                    if (contentView.getPaddingBottom() != diff) {
                        //set the padding of the contentView for the keyboard
                        contentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, diff);
                    }
                } else {
                    //check if the padding is != 0 (if yes reset the padding)
                    if (contentView.getPaddingBottom() != 0) {
                        //reset the padding of the contentView
                        contentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        public KeyboardUtil(Activity act, View contentView) {
            this.decorView = act.getWindow().getDecorView();
            this.contentView = contentView;

            //only required on newer android versions. it was working on API level 19
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Helper to hide the keyboard
         *
         * @param act
         */
        public static void hideKeyboard(Activity act) {
            if (act != null && act.getCurrentFocus() != null) {
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) act.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(act.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }

        public void enable() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                decorView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener);
            }
        }

        public void disable() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                decorView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(onGlobalLayoutListener);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61813321/2914140:

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog
    dialog.behavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    return dialog
}
```

But if a layout is not tall enough, you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/66287187/2914140 instead. It will open BottomSheetDialog almost fullscreen:

```
<style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
  <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize|stateVisible</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Compose you can just add Modifier.imePadding() on the most bottom Composable. Then the keyboard top will snap to that element instead.

Answer (score -2):

Fiddling with BottomSheetDialogFragment wasn't really worth it. So I just changed it to a simple `DialogFragment` and just set its gravity to bottom:

```
window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Worked like a charm.