# BottomSheetDialog - How to show all content

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottom-sheet

I'm using [BottomSheetDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog.html) to show list of option. The issue I have is that some items are hidden initially (user has to swipe up to reveal all content). How can I force [BottomSheetDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog.html) to show all content?

I extended [BottomSheetDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetDialog.html) and used "setContent" to set bottom sheet dialog's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dialog_title_text_size"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Title"
        tools:textColor="@color/blue" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/attachment_picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_attachment_picker" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Check this answer, it's bit hacky but it works ok: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50798800/2239198

Comment: Thanks palimad, I ended up using https://github.com/michaelbel/BottomSheet