# How can the dimensions of the dialog for an EditTextPreference be customized?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm working on an app with a settings fragment written using the AndroidX Preference library, and I would like to be able to display the dialog window for an EditTextPreference at the bottom of the screen using the screen's full width instead of in the center, like how WhatsApp does it:

[WhatsApp status screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWtvb.jpg)

How can this be done? I couldn't find a solution when I searched for this, so I decided to ask this question myself.

Comment: what is your programming language? java or kotlin? and or use cross platform framework like react native - xamarin - flutter and so on ....

Comment: and  plz see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48002290/9681220  => maybe help you

Comment: I'm using Kotlin.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, the question you posted isn't applicable in my case because I'm not using the EditText control directly. The code for the app can be found here: https://github.com/BOINC/boinc