# How to show keyboard below view in bottom sheet Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, keyboard

I have a bottom sheet with data . about : Edittext, recycler view . I want to show keyboard below edittext and override recyclerview . As image . how i can ? thank you !

I want to show keyboard below edittext and override recyclerview

Comment: check this out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48002290/show-entire-bottom-sheet-with-edittext-above-keyboard

Comment: Thanks. i was try this but i want to keyboard override recyclerView.