# Keyboard below the fragment view

Tags: android

this is what i want
[image]I am using the `BottomsheetFragment` what i want is the keyboard should be below the view . but in my case keyboard is overlaping the fragment view .

here is my xml file [check my code here](https://pastebin.com/raw/zycFkGSE)

```
and i am getting this output
```

[image: overlapping keyboard]

Comment: Please don't link to necessary information off-site. You need to provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Comment: Kindly  add following code in your AndroidManifest.xml activity - android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and check

Comment: @ShadowDroid i checked its not workin for me

Comment: I have edited comment initially I mentioned adjustPan sorry for that but adjustResize should work for detail information you can check https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft

Comment: @ShadowDroid even adjustResize does not work

Comment: did you tried this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/39331020/7917629 ?

Answer (score 0):

> I have created a sample app and tested on the bottomsheet xml provided
>   by you. By adding
>   `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"` in
>   manifest file did work.

So Manifest file looks as below.

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Alternatively you can set this attribute dynamically as well inside onCreate in Activity class as follows

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

> I have tried both ways on an sample app

Comment: i have no issue with the activity .  issue is when i have activity and  that activity holds the BottomSheetFragment . in this case the fragment keyboard is giving me the issue

Comment: Device Windows--->has Activity-->holds fragment-->in above case BottomSheetFragment. So Keyboard is associated with Window(i.e Activity which is root from application point of view.)

Comment: @NitinZagade As mentioned I tried the code in sample app. If you want I can post the screenshot. give me sometime. Bythe way just let me know if you are using any styles. kindly post your style.xml