# Bottom sheet (NOT DIALOG FRAGMENT) open with keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

My bottom sheet opened with keyboard if i open keyboard first time. This is not problem of code.

I tried to change windowSoftInputMode for my activity. But this does't help me

Some screenshots:

[fist open](https://pp.userapi.com/c851328/v851328907/11d6ae/5v8tiVwmtus.jpg)

[open keyboard](https://pp.userapi.com/c850036/v850036907/185a0f/urWKrsUeU-A.jpg)

[hide keyboard](https://pp.userapi.com/c854220/v854220907/476c7/3u1zt-6XBkk.jpg)

Comment: i found solution. Just make bottom sheet visibility = gone. But this is not the answer