# SnackBar is not showing properly if the keyboard is opened in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-keypad, android-snackbar

I am using snack bar for displaying information, it is working fine if keyboard is not opened. If keyboard is opened the snack bar message displaying whole screen not displaying properly i am using android 5.5. I added this line `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"` in my activity manifest but still same issue. Please help me for this issue. Please find the image below[image: screen shot]. My snack bar code is `Snackbar.make(coordinator,getString(R.string.validation_plz_enter_mandatory_flds, UtilConstants.ERROR_CODE_UI_2000),Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();`

Comment: And where exactly is the `SnackBar`, because I can't see it from the image?

Comment: the black color is snackbar

Comment: Can you add the code for the snackBar?

Comment: i added my code

Comment: share your xml file. that will better explain the situation.

Comment: Your Answer is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469019/snackbar-is-not-showing-properly-if-the-keyboard-is-opened-in-android/52073565#52073565

Answer (score 5):

This is the Correct Solution of this problem: `SnackBar show Above the SoftInput 
(Keyboard)` - (when Keyboard is Open)

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

tag into your activity tag of the manifest.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you initialized your snackbar like below code:

```
snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), <Your message>, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

or you have used your own layout??

Because if we use android's own UI element(android.R.id.content) it manages to show on valid UI of their own. You should first try this.

Comment: i am using own layout

Comment: try android's own UI element(android.R.id.content)

Comment: @AndroidGeek Thank you dude. Its very simple and elagent solution. It also solves my another one issue in displaying snackbar.

Answer (score 2):

Put this property in your Manifest file to your proper activity.

```
        <activity android:name=".YourActivity"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

Comment: I already have android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" due to my layout, so I can't use adjustResize. Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

If your using `CoordinatorLayout` with `AppBar` and `NestedLayout` with `EditText` inside, it won't work.
This is a bug in support lib, reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37108215#c7).

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32690553/1729085).

You can use a workaround by wrapping the `CoordinatorLayout` with another Constraint/Relative Layout (PS I've not tried RealtiveLayout but works using ConstraintLayout) and use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.
with referenced to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36322516/1729085) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just Hide the KeyBoard where you call your SnackBar using below code:

```
  InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(parentLayout.getWindowToken(), 0); // parentLayout is your main layout of an activity
```