# NestedScrollView not scrolling with CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-design-library, android-nestedscrollview, androiddesignsupport

Trying to scroll content within `CoordinatorLayout` with `NestedScrollView` is not working for following layout for fragment:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="24dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <!-- Scrollable content -->

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How can I make the content inside `NestedScrollView` scrollable? `windowSoftInput` is set to `adjustResize` for the hosting activity and the theme is `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`. Also the activity is not fullscreen.

Comment: are you trying to make collapsing layout?

Comment: @Mr.AF No. I'm using `CoordinatorLayout` to draw behind status bar

Comment: do you have scroll able view inside nested scroll view or it's empty?

Comment: I have a form inside nested scroll view, so there are number of views inside nested scroll view which should makes it scrollable

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Had to apply the workaround mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36322516 as nothing else was working for me. So marking this answer as accepted until a working solution is posted as an answer